# XIB messing up when opening with Xcode 5.0?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode4.5

I have my project which was created on Xcode 4.5. I have my XIB file and i have several subviews in it. ( uiimageviews/textviews..) . I already design my UI using interface builder. Now when i opened my project in xcode 5.0, there are some uiimageviews ( image set via interface builder itself) which doesnot appear. Why is that happening?

XCODE 4.6 :

[image]

When i opened teh same XIB in XCODE 5.0 and see the size inspector

[image]

Comment: are you using Auto Layout ?

Comment: Your screen shot shows origin values is - 560 Thats y..

Comment: Check all the other sub view origin values...

Comment: Hello @Ganapathy well yeah that weird.. in xcode 5 its 0. Yeah i am getting this for some uiimageviews, not all subviews.

Comment: But how come this translation when i opened the XIB in xcode 5.0. Also see the height and width its became 0